# Verifying the phone number

Tags: android, telephonymanager

In my application first thing the user should do is the registration. For that i need the phone no. So the user will give their 10 digit number. Now i need to verfy the user inputed the same number which holds by the phone. How to do that ? i tried `.getLine1Number()` but it is returing nothing.

After pressing the register button i am calling a url which will send a verification code to the phone number was inputed by the user. Till that i am showing a alert dialog. After receiving the message only i am dismissing the dialoge box.

So the problem happens when the user give a valid number which may not their number.

PS: I need to get the response through message only.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358380/phone-number-validation-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958665/validation-for-a-cell-number-in-android

Comment: getLine1Number function doesnt work on some GSM service providers. Instead of it you can use the serial number of the sim, it is also a unique one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only few service providers provide phone number via getLine1Number() method. Instead you can get a unique number for each sim using getSimSerialNumber() method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you set permissions in Manifest READ_PHONE_STATE ?
2. Method still can return null

> Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.