# How to refer method that is in the java class of src folder from html file in phonegap

Tags: android, api, cordova

I have User registration page in Phonegap www folder.I want to validate email id and phone number using native android functions.How do I do that?

Comment: Please refer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358380/phone-number-validation-android & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958665/validation-for-a-cell-number-in-android- for phone number detection.

Comment: And this link for mail validation- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355899/android-email-edittext-validation & this blog will also help you - http://chandan-tech.blogspot.in/2010/11/validating-email-address-pattern-in.html , http://www.technotalkative.com/android-validate-email-address/

Answer (score 0):

We have to write JS interface to execute java code from javascript.

Write following code in your onCreate method:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
             {
                public void performClick(String emailAdress, String phoneNo)
                {
                   // Validate email address and Phone number here
                }
             },"MyAndroid");
}
}
```

To call JS interface in phonegap app, write javascript function:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("validateButton").addEventListener('touchstart',touchPagePressed);// you can use 'onclick' also
function touchPagePressed()
{
   // MyAndroid interface will execute java's performClick method
   MyAndroid.performClick($("#emailId").val(),$("#phoneNo").val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why to use webview in java class and how to declare webview in xml file

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html go thr with this document, you'll get it

Comment: My index.html file contains the view with necessary widgets.Is it necessary to declare webview in MainActivity?

Comment: To access webView setting, you have to get the instance of WebView then only you can execute javascript interface.

Comment: where to declare webview? Is it in main.xml of layout or res/xml file

Comment: yes, it is in main.xml, check the above link in detail, you'll get the clear picture.

Comment: It is different from wat u have given above.Here in activity extending Droidgap but in the phonegap link they are extending cordova interface. Am using cordova 5.0.am facing issues

Comment: Can you please help with proper example

Comment: `WebSettings webSettings = super.getSettings();`, plz try super.getSettings()