# Email and phone Number Validation in android

Tags: android

I have a registration form in my application which I am trying to validate. I'm facing some problems with my validation while validating the phone number and email fields.

Here is my code:

```
private boolean validate() {

    String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";
    //String email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

    if (name.length() > 25) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pls enter less the 25 character in user name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    } else if (name.length() == 0 || number.length() == 0 || email.length() == 
             0 || subject.length() == 0 || message.length() == 0) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pls fill the empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    } else if (email.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern)) { 

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"valid email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    } else if(!email.getText().toString().matches(emailPattern)) { 

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Valid Email Address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    } else if(number.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern)) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "phone number is valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    } else if(!number.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern)) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid 10 digit phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have used this code above for the validation. The problem I'm facing is in the phone number and email validation, only one validation is working. For example, if I comment out the phone number validation, the email validation is working properly. If I comment out the email validation, the phone number validation is working. If use both validations, it's not working.

Comment: check this one http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/04/name-phone-number-email-validation.html

Answer (score 85, accepted):

## For Email Address Validation

```
private boolean isValidMail(String email) {

    String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    return Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING).matcher(email).matches();

}
```

**OR**

```
private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
   return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

## For Mobile Validation

For Valid Mobile You need to consider 7 digit to 13 digit because some country have 7 digit mobile number. If your main target is your own country then you can match with the length. Assuming India has 10 digit mobile number. Also we can not check like mobile number must starts with 9 or 8 or anything.

For mobile number I used this two Function:

```
private boolean isValidMobile(String phone) {
    if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", phone)) {
        return phone.length() > 6 && phone.length() <= 13;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**OR**

```
private boolean isValidMobile(String phone) {
    return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();    
}
```

Comment: This control is not enough for validate phone number. User might paste a string like "abcdefgh" and it will return true.

Comment: Yea the type "phone" is neat as well.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu I got my mistakes and update my answer.

Comment: android.util.Patterns..PHONE.matcher(phone).matches() not worked for me

Comment: [PHONE patterns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#PHONE)

android.util.Patterns.PHONE: This pattern is intended for searching for things that look like they might be phone numbers in arbitrary text, not for validating whether something is in fact a phone number. It will miss many things that are legitimate phone numbers.

Comment: OR one liner
  return !Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", tel_no_str) && !(tel_no_str.length() < 6 || tel_no_str.length() > 13);

Answer (score 53):

Use [**`Pattern`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) package  in Android to match the input validation for email and phone

Do like

```
android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(input).matches();
android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(input).matches();
```

Comment: @Nambi pls tell me where i have put this code im new for this android development.

Comment: Doc says it's not for validating whether something is in fact a phone number. It will miss many things that are legitimate phone numbers.

Comment: PHONE pattern in Patterns class is used for searching only.

Comment: This is not enough, you still can add dots (.) or more than 13 chars...

Comment: This is not valid answer for check valid phone number

Answer (score 15):

Android has [build-in patterns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html) for email, phone number, etc, that you can use if you are building for Android **API level 8 and above.**

```
private boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence email) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(CharSequence phoneNumber) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        return Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phoneNumber).matches();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) dont use this because it will return true if there is single space " ". use email.trim().equals("");

Comment: !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) will return true but Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches(); won't. The final result will be correct.

Comment: yeah i m wid u. I just said that Use that for check empty.

Comment: From android source code: The PHONE pattern is intended for searching for things that look like they might be phone numbers in arbitrary text, not for validating whether something is in fact a phone number.  It will miss many things that are legitimate phone numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
public class Validation {

    public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
        return false;
        } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    } 

    public static final boolean isValidPhoneNumber(CharSequence target) {
        if (target.length()!=10) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

He want an elegant and proper solution try this small regex pattern matcher.

This is specifically for India.(First digit can't be zero and and then can be any 9 digits)

`return mobile.matches("[1-9][0-9]{9}");`

Pattern Breakdown:-

`[1-9]` matches first digit and checks if number(integer) lies between(inclusive) 1 to 9
`[0-9]{9}` matches the same thing but `{9}` tells the pattern that it has to check for upcoming all 9 digits.

Now the {9} part may vary for different countries so you may have array which tells the number of digits allowed in phone number. Some countries also have significance for zero ahead of number, so you may have exception for those and design a separate regex patterns for those countries phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

in `Kotlin` you can use `Extension function` to validate input

// for Email validation

```
 fun String.isValidEmail(): Boolean =
        this.isNotEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this).matches()
```

// for Phone validation

```
fun String.isValidMobile(phone: String): Boolean {
    return Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The built in PHONE pattern matcher does not work in all cases.

So far, this is the best solution I have found to validate a phone number (code in Kotlin, extension of String)

```
fun String.isValidPhoneNumber() : Boolean {
    val patterns =  "^\\s*(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\\d{3})[-. )]*(\\d{3})[-. ]*(\\d{4})(?: *x(\\d+))?\\s*$"
    return Pattern.compile(patterns).matcher(this).matches()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
extMobileNo.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(extMobileNo));

private boolean validateMobile()    {   

    String mobile =extMobileNo.getText().toString().trim();
    if(mobile.isEmpty()||!isValidMobile(mobile)||extMobileNo.getText().toString().toString().length()<10 || mobile.length()>13 )

    {
            inputLayoutMobile.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_mobile));
        requestFocus(extMobileNo);
        return false;
    }

    else {
        inputLayoutMobile.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}

private static boolean isValidMobile(String mobile)
{
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(mobile)&& Patterns.PHONE.matcher(mobile).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//validation class

public class EditTextValidation {

```
public static boolean isValidText(CharSequence target) {
    return target != null && target.length() != 0;
}

public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}

public static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(CharSequence target) {
    if (target.length() != 10) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```

//activity or fragment

```
    val userName = registerNameET.text?.trim().toString()
    val mobileNo = registerMobileET.text?.trim().toString()
    val emailID = registerEmailIDET.text?.trim().toString()

    when {
        !EditTextValidation.isValidText(userName) -> registerNameET.error = "Please provide name"
        !EditTextValidation.isValidEmail(emailID) -> registerEmailIDET.error =
            "Please provide email"
        !EditTextValidation.isValidPhoneNumber(mobileNo) -> registerMobileET.error =
            "Please provide mobile number"
        else -> {
            showToast("Hello World")
        }
    }
```

**Hope it will work for you... It is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I am always using this methode for Email Validation:

```
public boolean checkForEmail(Context c, EditText edit) {
    String str = edit.getText().toString();
    if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(str).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    Toast.makeText(c, "Email is not valid...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkForEmail() {
        Context c;
        EditText mEtEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        String mStrEmail = mEtEmail.getText().toString();
        if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mStrEmail).matches()) {
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Email is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }


    public boolean checkForMobile() {
        Context c;
        EditText mEtMobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMobile);
        String mStrMobile = mEtMobile.getText().toString();
        if (android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(mStrMobile).matches()) {
            return true;
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Phone No is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: checkForEmail(); 
checkForMobile();

Comment: checkForEmail(); 
checkForMobile(); these are calls to that fuctions,you call add to theme where you want so that the function will call

Answer (score 0):

For check email and phone number you need to do that

```
   public static boolean isValidMobile(String phone) {
        boolean check = false;
        if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", phone)) {
            if (phone.length() < 9 || phone.length() > 13) {
                // if(phone.length() != 10) {
                check = false;
                // txtPhone.setError("Not Valid Number");
            } else {
                check = android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();
            }
        } else {
            check = false;
        }
        return check;
    }

    public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        boolean check;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

        m = p.matcher(email);
        check = m.matches();

        return check;
    }

  

    String enter_mob_or_email="";//1234567890 or test@gmail.com
    if (isValidMobile(enter_mob_or_email)) {
           // Phone number is valid
    }else isEmailValid(enter_mob_or_email){
          //Email is valid 
    }else{
         // Not valid email or phone number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:hint="Enter Email or Phone Number"/>
```

**Java**

```
private AppCompatEditText et_email_contact;
private boolean validEmail = false, validPhone = false;     

et_email_contact = findViewById(R.id.et_email_contact);
et_email_contact.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String regex = "^[+]?[0-9]{10,13}$";
        String emailContact = s.toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailContact)) {
            Log.e("Validation", "Enter Mobile No or Email");
        } else {
            if (emailContact.matches(regex)) {
                Log.e("Validation", "Valid Mobile No");
                validPhone = true;
                validEmail = false;
            } else if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailContact).matches()) {
                Log.e("Validation", "Valid Email Address");
                validPhone = false;
                validEmail = true;
            } else {
                validPhone = false;
                validEmail = false;
                Log.e("Validation", "Invalid Mobile No or Email");
            }
        }
    }
});

if (validPhone || validEmail) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Valid Email or Phone no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "InValid Email or Phone no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> private fun isValidMobileNumber(s: String): Boolean {

```
    // 1) Begins with 0 or 91
    // 2) Then contains 6 or 7 or 8 or 9.
    // 3) Then contains 9 digits
    val p: Pattern = Pattern.compile("(0|91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}")
    // Pattern class contains matcher() method
    // to find matching between given number
    val m: Matcher = p.matcher(s)
    return m.find() && m.group().equals(s)
}
```