# How to do Phone number validation in Android?

Tags: android

How to validate phone number in EditText for Android?

I tried using this code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
   />
```

But it will not work for special characters. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email and phone Number Validation in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505336/email-and-phone-number-validation-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Method:

```
private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phone) {

    if (!phone.trim().equals("") && phone.length() > 10) {
            return Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phone).matches();
    }

        return false;
}
```

Comment: should be && in that if

Comment: `> 10` seems too strict; US numbers are usually 10 digits for instance, as are some UK numbers and all Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

So far, this is the best solution I have found to validate a phone number (code in Kotlin, extension of String)

```
fun String.isValidPhoneNumber() : Boolean {
    val patterns =  "^\\s*(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\\d{3})[-. )]*(\\d{3})[-. ]*(\\d{4})(?: *x(\\d+))?\\s*$"
    return Pattern.compile(patterns).matcher(this).matches()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
private boolean isValidphone(String bphone) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(bphone) && 
    bphone.length() == 10 && 
    TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(bphone);
}
```