# Kotlin - How to store a table with 4D data by using collection/data class

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

Is it any Kotlin collection/data class able to store the table data as shown below?
I can only figure out the way to store the item and value as below:

```
var WorkA = mapOf{"Name" to "AA", "Gender" to "Female"}...
```

but I can't figure out how to link the "verify result".

Please give me some advice as I'm a newbie. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `Worker` data class with the fields listed in `Item` column as properties and some boolean properties representing validity of those fields.

```
data class Worker(val name:String, val gender :String, val age :Int, val tel:String,val email:String){

    var isNameValid : Boolean = false
        get(){
            return name.isNotEmpty()
        }

    var isGenderValid : Boolean = false
        get(){
            return gender.equals("Male",true) || gender.equals("Female",true)
        }

    var isAgeValid : Boolean = false
        get(){
            return age >= 18 && age<=60
        }
    var isTelValid : Boolean = false
        get(){
            //TODO : validate telephone number
            return true
        }
    var isEmailValid: Boolean = false
        get(){
            //TODO: validate email.
            return true
        }
}
```

You can create `Worker` objects and use them as elements of an `Worker` array/list.

```
val workerA = Worker("A", "Male",  18, "123", "a@mail.com")
val workerB = Worker("B", "Female",  20, "122", "b@mail.com")

val workers: List<Worker> = listOf(workerA, workerB)
println(workers[0].isNameValid)
```

As your question does not provide the validation rules for fields and the table provided does not make it obvious, I have left implementation of getters up to you. Check the questions linked below.

[How should I validate an e-mail address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address)

[Email and phone Number Validation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505336/email-and-phone-number-validation-in-android/22505377)