# mobile number validation with special character in android

Tags: java, android

I am an android Beginner,

I want to validate phone numbers with special character + , ( , ) , -  and all digits

example  (123)456-7894

I tried this code

```
public boolean validCellPhone(String number){
        boolean b=true;

        String MOBILE_PATTERN = "[(,),-][0-9]{10,16}";    // ddm validating

       pattern = Pattern.compile(MOBILE_PATTERN);  
       matcher = pattern.matcher(cellph.getText().toString());  
       if (!matcher.matches()) { 


           cellph.requestFocus();
         b=false;
       }  
       else{

           b=true;
       }         
       return b;
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6358825v

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email and phone Number Validation in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505336/email-and-phone-number-validation-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
public boolean validCellPhone(String number){

   return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(number).matches();
}
```

Comment: Best trick I found,set android:inputType="number" in xml, it won't allow user to enter any special character like  @, #% at all.