# Android PhoneNumberUtils isWellFormedSmsAddress

Tags: android

What is a well formed sms address?

I am doing this in my code:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(mPhone) && !PhoneNumberUtils.isWellFormedSmsAddress(mPhone)) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.cellphone_error));
    alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.cellphone_error_hint));
    alertDialog.show();
    return;
}
```

However, I can't seem to input any set of numbers to activate this code. For some reason, everything seems to qualify as a well formed sms address. How does this error check work?

Should I just use `isGlobalPhoneNumber` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line after looking at either one of those methods you probably want to use your own RegEx to validate a number such as those used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6358825/1435985) depending on your requirements.

Reason being is that `PhoneNumberUtils.isWellFormedSmsAddress(...)` extracts the network part of the passed in `String` using `PhoneNumberUtils.extractNetworkPortion(...)` and basically checks if that network portion has dialable digits.

Problem is `PhoneNumberUtils.extractNetworkPortion(...)` removes most non digits  so `+18fvg12` becomes `+1812` and still passes.

PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber (...) appears a bit more useful and 
makes sure the phone number matches the RegEx `[\+]?[0-9.-]+`.

This still might not be desirable though as `+-----598--` still passes as an example.